# Pytorch model doesn't fit for some reason

Tags: python, pytorch, data-science

I'm learning Pytorch so I decided to participate in kaggle competition [DigitRecognition](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/digit-recognizer/overview). It seems to me that eveything is correct but during the training the model accuracy was get worse and worst. I think that I've made some unnoticable mistake which spoils the model maybe connected with custom DataSet class (*MyDataset*) but I can't find it myself. Please, somebody help me.
Here is [colab notebook with all solution](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1th6k4Iw06ywTjE_myCw4j_O7umpqylfW?usp=sharing).

Comment: set lower learning rate of optimizer (like 0.0003 or equivalently 3e-4)